# How to type-hint a classmethod's `Self` return type

Tags: python

Let's say I have a class that has class-/staticmethod which are akin to constructors, something to the tune of

```py
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        ...  # something

    @classmethod
    def from_bar(cls, bar):
        if bar.is_foobar():
            return cls('foobar')
        else:
            return cls()
```

My question is how to correctly type-hint the `from_bar`-method. As far as I can see there is a dilemma here:

- Either `from_bar` is a `classmethod` that returns `typing.Self`; `def from_bar(cls, bar: Bar) -> typing.Self`. However this is not actually correct, because a subclass `Foobar(Foo)` would return a `Foobar` (by means of `return cls(...)`) while hinting a `Foo` via `typing.Self`. This is a type-error.
- Or `from_bar` is a `staticmethod` that returns `'Foo'` via late-binding; `def from_bar(bar: Bar) -> 'Foo'`. This however is not possible because a `staticmethod` defined on `Foo` can't refer to `Foo` (by means of `return Foo(...)` as the class is currently being defined - unlike the type-hint there is not late binding to identifiers.

Am I overcomplicating things?

Comment: "This however is not possible because a staticmethod defined on Foo can't refer to Foo (by means of return Foo(...) as the class is currently being defined" -- sure it can, try it! The body of the method is executed some time after the class has been defined.

Comment: `typing.Self` hints the corresponding subclass instead of `Foo` in the subclass, as shown in the [official documentation example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self).